# Laravel NPM error "npm run dev " in command line I am using Laravel v8.83.27 (PHP v8.1.0)

Tags: authentication, user-interface, npm

```
  ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[4]!./resources/sass/app.scss)
  Module Error (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

  ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[4]!./resources/sass/app.scss)
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
      at process (C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\lib\engine\postcss.js:28:19)
      at Object.resolveUrlLoader (C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js:200:14)

  Child mini-css-extract-plugin C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[1]!C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[2]!C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[3]!C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].use[4]!C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\resources\sass\app.scss compiled with 
2 errors and 1 warning

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleError: Module Error (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at Object.emitError (C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:614:6)
    at getSassImplementation (C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\utils.js:56:21)
    at Object.loader (C:\xampp\htdocs\example-app\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:27:59)
```

I have change this in my package.json file

```
   mix.webpackConfig({
stats: {
    children: true,
},});
```

also I run this command `npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact` but still error